# meteor deletes the rest from subarray while updating

Tags: mongodb, meteor

The entry is created like this:

```
Nodes.insert({name : node1, conf :{flag1: true, flag2: true } });
```

I wan't to update **flag1** from my subarray. 
This is my code:

```
Nodes.update(Session.get("node"), {$set:   {conf :{ flag1 : false }}});
```

When I call the snippet - flag2 gets stripped from my array. I know I could probably add that part into the update notion - but the subarray conf will have lots of entries this could get a bit tedious .. . The order of the flags can change, too. Is there a magic potion for this. The mongodb document is not very clear about this.The conf.$ dot notation throws an error.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `$set conf.flag1`. Like this:

```
Nodes.update(Session.get("node"), {$set:   {"conf.flag1" : false}});
```

The $ positional operator is only used for arrays. Standard dot notation is used for subdocuments.